# resize nivo slider box

Tags: html, css

I just got a template but I don't know how to re-size the whole slider to make it smaller along with my images. I can re-size the images just fine.  I want the whole surrounding box to be smaller.

Comment: show us the html n css

Answer (score 0):

Find the width definition for it in the CSS and alter it that way.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what the code is. Can you send me a link or post the code somewhere?